# How Can A Batch Transaction Be Executed From A Nested Loop To Update Variables In The Outer Loop?

Tags: apex, batch, governorlimits, asynchronous, stateful

### How can we update a variable in an outer loop from a Batch transaction in an inner loop?

For example, consider a example scenario where you must track the even Apples (per Basket) inside multiple Baskets.

In order to track the even Apples, you MUST run part of the logic in its own transaction inside the inner Apple loop.

**For example:**

```
/**
 * Track the Even Apples in the Baskets (Requires Batch Transactions)
 */

for (Integer basket = 0; basket < 5; basket++) {
    
    // Note 1: trackEvenApples needs to be updated synchronously based on the inner loop to be used after the inner loop ...
    List<String> trackEvenApples = new List<String>();
    
    for (Integer apple = 0; apple < 5; apple++) {
        
        // Note 2: In this scenario, this logic MUST run in its own batch transaction due to Salesforce limits ...
        if (Math.mod(apple, 2) == 0) {
            trackEvenApples.add('Basket Apple (Even): ' + basket + '.' + apple);
        }
        
    }
    
    // Note 3: Proceed to use trackEvenApples, and perform additional miscellaneous logic ...
    System.debug('Constructor - trackEvenApples:');
    System.debug(trackEvenApples);
    
}
```

Since Batch transactions are asynchronous, don't always complete in the order that they were executed, and are executed in their own separate transaction, it doesn't seem like we would be able to update the `trackEvenApples` List properly, nor use the `trackEvenApples` List after the inner loop.

Is this somehow tied in with `Database.Stateful`?

How can we update the `trackEvenApples` List from the Batch transaction called from the inner loop?

Answer (score 3):

You can't. It's not possible to share variable access across transaction boundaries. `Database.Stateful` allows you to preserve state from one batch invocation into the next, but it doesn't allow live, bidirectional access. In fact, any asynchronous Apex you enqueue from a synchronous context cannot even begin executing until the synchronous transaction successfully commits.

> Since Batch transactions are asynchronous, don't always complete in the order that they were executed, and are executed in their own separate transaction, it doesn't seem like we would be able to update the trackEvenApples List properly, nor use the trackEvenApples List after the inner loop.

You're quite right here, based on a simple reading of the scenario proposed (a reading that I share on first glance!)

I suspect though that (a) this is a very badly framed problem and (b) you and I are both misreading the intent for that reason. I think that the sense of the request is probably to convert this *entire* piece of code into a batch class (using `Database.Stateful`, as you already intuited) that iterates over five "baskets", not to run a batch class from inside a `for` loop (which is a bad idea anyway).

If this is some kind of hiring exam... I'd be awfully skeptical, because based on what I see here, it's a badly done one.